# Call BQ stored procedures in Dataflow

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have set of stored procedures that I wish to run back to back in sequence so that I automate their execution. Cloud Dataflow is a good option to perform etl and post processing steps. But the issue with that is it just accepts SELECT queries in the job. How do I make a call to these procedures that i have saved in BQ from a dataflow job?
If cloud dataflow does not offer this help then what can be an alternative to achieve this? I dont want to use BQ scheduled query option.

P.S. When I say stored procedure, it involves multiple inserts, deletes, updates, truncates in the same script. I don't have SELECT there

Comment: Why not use Cloud Functions that you can trigger with a HTTP request or some other way instead of Dataflow?